# PostgreSQL declaring variables with explicit data types

Tags: sql, postgresql, variables

I have read over the documentation and several SO posts, but it still feels unclear how variables are declared and assigned in Postgres... This is what I originally tried to do:

```
SET SEARCH_PATH = PsychoProductions;
declare var_person_id   INT;
select var_person_id = (
        select id 
        from person 
        where 
                first_name = prm_first_name AND
                last_name = prm_last_name AND
                organization = prm_organization
        );
/* 
Result:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INT"
LINE 2:     DECLARE var_person_id   INT;
                                    ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "INT"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 70
*/
```

It is simple but it doesn't work... I'm kind of new at Postgres syntax, and I was hoping to get some help figuring this out, as I would like to explicitly declare data types, if possible, before setting data to variables.

Do any of you know what the heck I am missing to explicitly declare data types while setting a variable?

## **EDIT 1: 09-05-2013**

Some have pointed out that variables have to be used within a function. I don't believe that's completely the case with Postgres (I know it is with MySQL, and is not with T-SQL) but to the point, here is the above code, in context within a function. I will test what has been pointed out in one answer, shortly, and accept accordingly. So here is the full code so far:

```
set search_path = PsychoProductions;
create or replace function fcn_Insert_person (
        -- "person" table
        prm_role_id             text, -- table default 'Customer'
        prm_first_name          text,
        prm_last_name           text,
        prm_organization        text,
        prm_website             text,
        prm_default_Billing_Method_ID   text, -- table default 'Net 30'
        prm_active              BOOLEAN,
        -- "address" table
        prm_address_type_id     text, -- table default 'Unique'
        prm_address             text,
        prm_city                text,
        prm_state               text,
        prm_zip_code            text,
        -- "email" table
        prm_email_address       text,
        prm_email_type_id       text, -- table default 'Business'
        -- "phone" table
        prm_phone_number        text,
        prm_phone_type_id       text  -- table default 'Main'
        ) 
        returns setof Person 
as

$delimiter$

begin
set search_patch = PsychoProductions;
start transaction;
insert into person (
        role_id,
        first_name,
        last_name,
        organization,
        website,
        default_billing_method_id,
        active
        )
values (
        prm_role_id,
        prm_first_name,
        prm_last_name,
        prm_organization,
        prm_website,
        prm_default_Billing_Method_ID,
        prm_active
        );
commit; 

start transaction;
declare var_person_id   int;
select var_person_id = (
        select id 
        from person 
        where 
                first_name = prm_first_name AND
                last_name = prm_last_name AND
                organization = prm_organization
        );
-- and this is where I got stuck
```

## **EDIT 2: 09-06-2013**

I used the `select into myVar ...` syntax but now I'm getting a completely different problem... Should I ask a new question?

Error:

```
ERROR:  column "var_person_id" does not exist
LINE 81:         var_person_id,
                 ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: column "var_person_id" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Character: 2220
```

Code:

```
start transaction;
-- declare var_person_id   int;
select id into var_person_id 
        from person 
        where 
                first_name = prm_first_name AND
                last_name = prm_last_name AND
                organization = prm_organization;

insert into address (
        person_id,
        address_type_id,
        address,
        city,
        state,
        zip_code
        )
values (
        var_person_id, -- error here
        prm_address_type_id,
        prm_address,
        prm_city,
        prm_state,
        per_zip_code
        );
```

Comment: As Dwayne pointed out, variables can only be used in procedural code. But why do you need that? If you want to re-use the result of that select later you can do that with a sub-select. If you need it multiple times use a common table expression. Maybe you should show us your _real_ problem.

Comment: I added the code context, thanks @a_horse_with_no_name - Do you think I'm just stuck in T-SQL thinking and there is a more natural method to do this?

Comment: So you are trying to retrieve the `id` that was generated by the `insert`? If that is true, use `insert ... values () returning id` or use `currval()` or `lastval()`  to access the last generated sequence value in a subsequent statement. Or use a combination of data modifying CTEs

Comment: I am, and what you suggested will likely work... but, generally, how in the world are variables useful in Postgres, if it is so difficult to use them??

Comment: I don't understand what's so difficult in using them. They are useful in the same way as in any programming language. But you can only use them inside a *program*, i.e. a stored function (this is no different to Oracle, DB2, Firebird and many other DBMS). I still think you are approaching the problem in a wrong way. Instead of asking "how can I use variables" you should explain your *real* problem. I'm pretty sure there is a much better solution that insisting on using variables in a way they were not meant to.

Comment: OK that sounds like I need to change my thinking about it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only declare variables inside a function (stored procedure). Try something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(prm_first_name text,prm_last_name text) 
RETURNS SET OF int $$
DECLARE
    var_person_id int;
BEGIN
    SELECT id INTO var_person_id
        FROM person,var_parameter
        WHERE first_name = prm_first_name 
        AND last_name = prm_last_name
        AND organization = prm_organization;

    -- OR

    var_person_id := (SELECT id FROM ...);

    -- use it later like this:

    RETURN QUERY SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE id=var_person_id;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Comment: But you never demonstrated use of the `var_person_id` variable.

Comment: @DwayneTowell I added the rest of my code as an edit, I have been trying to declare within a function. The only problem I have with your method is that `SELECT ... INTO myVar` infers the data type, as opposed to declaring it explicitly, and that is what I was trying to do... But if there is a more "Postgres" way to do this, I'm open. I guess I'm stuck in T-SQL/MySQL mode for the moment and perhaps not grasping a core concept of Postgres...

Comment: @Phrancis: what do you mean with "*infers the data type*". Any variable you use must be declared with a data type. PL/pgSQL is a strongly type language (as is SQL). You can't declare variables without a type. Specifying the type shouldn't be a problem because the column you are select also has a type. The variable needs to have the same (or compatible) type.

Comment: I'm trying to explicitly declare a data type on the variable; where if I tell the engine this var should be an `int` and instead it is passed `'foo'` it won't take it...

Comment: @Phrancis: of course you can't. `'foo'` is a character literal not an integer. So why on earth would you want to store a character value to a variable defined as a number? Dwayne's answer clearly shows you how to do what you apparently want to do.

Comment: OK that sounds like I need to change my thinking about it. Thanks a lot!